# xgalley breaks memoir and ntheorem

Tags: memoir, expl3, ntheorem, l3galley, xgalley

Another question from me about the experimental expl3 package `xgalley`: This time, simply loading the package causes problems with `memoir` and `ntheorem`. Consider the below MWE. When I load `xgalley`, the following things happen:

- The spacing in my `\maketitle` is broken
- The theorem becomes indented, which was not the case before.
- An empty second page is added to my document (this cannot be seen on the screenshots below)

Can all of this be fixed?

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum,ntheorem}

\title{Blahblah}
\author{Me, myself, and I}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{xgalley}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

With `xgalley`:

[image]

Without `xgalley`:

[image]

Comment: When I open `xgalley.sty` the first thing I see is »EXPERIMENTAL CODE«.  Thus it should be expected to break things.  Then question is of course valid, though. (+1)

Comment: @HenriMenke: I am aware it is experimental. However, if it can be made to work, it can potentially become an extremely powerful and flexible replacement for `wrapfig`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't a fix. Imho regarding the experimental status of the code it is more important to find the problems currently.

So I looked in the `l3galley` code to find all redefinitions of standard LaTeX/TeX commands which perhaps could matter and setup a test environment.

With it you can restore the "old" meanings of the commands.

**Attention**: The commands are not independent, so it is quite possible that everything breaks if one restore the commands only partially. But for investigations this is nevertheless quite useful.

In your case one can so quite easily find out that the indentation is caused by the change of `\everypar`, while the spacing is an `\addvspace` problem. The empty page is caused by the `\clearpage` redefinition which does a `\newpage` and then inserts a box which isn't discarded as in the original `\clearpage` code -- this looks like a bug to me.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
%save the old definitions
\clist_set:Nn\l_tmpa_clist{
  clearpage,
  nobreak,
  noindent,
  vspace,
  @vspace,
  @xnewline,
  @newline,
  newline,
  addpenalty,
  addvspace,
  @afterheading,
  @hangfrom,
  @normalcr,
  @par,
  everypar
  }

\clist_map_inline:Nn\l_tmpa_clist{\cs_set_eq:cc{ORI#1}{#1}}
\cs_set_eq:NN \ORINewline\\
\cs_set_eq:Nc \ORIpar { @ @ par }
\skip_set_eq:NN\l_tmpa_skip\parskip
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ntheorem}

\title{Blahblah}
\author{Me, myself, and I}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{l3galley}

% Restore the old meanings, choose the one you want to test
\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
\clist_set:Nn\l_tmpa_clist{
%  clearpage,
%  nobreak,
%  noindent,
%  vspace,
%  @vspace,
%  @xnewline,
%  @newline,
%  newline,
%  addpenalty,
%  addvspace,
%  @afterheading,
%  @hangfrom,
%  @normalcr,
%  @par,
%  everypar
  }
\clist_map_inline:Nn\l_tmpa_clist{\cs_set_eq:cc{#1}{ORI#1}}
%\cs_set_eq:NN \\\ORINewline
%\cs_set_eq:cN  { @ @ par }\ORIpar
%\cs_set_eq:Nc \@normalcr { \cs_to_str:N \\ }
%\skip_set_eq:NN\parskip\l_tmpa_skip

\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother


\begin{document}

%wrong spacing between lists:
\begin{center}
blub
\end{center}
\vspace*{10pt}
\begin{center}
blub
\end{center}

{
\let\addvspace\ORIaddvspace

\begin{center}
blub
\end{center}
\vspace*{10pt}
\begin{center}
blub
\end{center}
}

\maketitle

\begin{theorem}
blub\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So would you say it is possible to fix?

Comment: Sure, the question is how and where and by whom. I already notified Joseph about the clearpage problem which imho is a l3galley bug.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Fixed in sources: I'll update CTAN perhaps tomorrow

Comment: @JosephWright How many of the bugs did you fix? :-)

Comment: @JosephWright Running the code in TL16, the extra page is gone, and the spacing is right in the page title. However, the theorem ist still wrongly indented. Any hope for a fix?