# How to typeset in two (or more) columns with xgalley?

Tags: xgalley

The `xgalley` package does not produce any output when using a `twocolumn` style option. Neither does it generate an error.

What's the right way to typeset in two (or more) columns with `xgalley`?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{xgalley}
\begin{document}
No output is produced.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you think there is a right way to use `twocolumn` with `xgalley`?

Comment: `xgalley` provides many convenient ways to shape paragraphs. Writing text in two or more columns is useful. Why not both?

Comment: That's not really my point. The point is that `twocolumn` is part of a system which is entirely distinct from that implemented by `xgalley`. If you want two-columns, you have to implement that using the facilities provided by `xgalley` (and `l3galley` underneath). You aren't trying to actually use this in a real document, are you? That's very brave!

Comment: Though I agree it shouldn't output nothing. I'd expect it to just typeset it normally - as if you didn't use `twocolumn` rather than producing no output at all.

Comment: Perhaps a better question is how to typeset in two columns using `xgalley`. Doesn't have to use the standard `twocolumn` option. Not a serious document. I'm investigating what `xgalley` can do.

Comment: Yes, I think that is the right question. Though it really shouldn't just eat the document. Especially without mentioning it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as if you found out why the original `\clearpage` code has this curious  `\write\m@ne{}\vbox{}`. See also the comment of this commit:
https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/80c3f9f763efe98ebf1b27ef1b8dab5e69a72027#diff-42b0cc1cd07f0fb15bdb3c15ba035c2d which was done after this question [xgalley breaks memoir and ntheorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309426/xgalley-breaks-memoir-and-ntheorem).

If one adds them back the page reappears:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{l3galley}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \clearpage
  {
    \mode_if_vertical:T
      {
        \int_compare:nNnT \@dbltopnum = { -1 }
          {
            \dim_compare:nNnT \tex_pagetotal:D < \topskip
              { \tex_hbox:D { } }
          }
      }
    \newpage
    %\galley_penalty_set_single:n { -\@Mi } %from l3galley
    %original code from latex.ltx:
     \write\m@ne{}
     \vbox{} 
     \penalty -\@Mi
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
No output is produced.\par
abc

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm just starting to investigate the LaTeX3 stuff. For the future, are the LaTeX3 styles expected to work with the standard LaTeX2e classes? i.e., should I just report this kind of thing as a bug or always ask here first? (I understand that things might well break with other packages.)

Comment: @DavidPurton This should probably be reported as a bug, if Ulrike hasn't done it already. I don't know if there's a general rule but all content disappearing when you use `twocoloumn` seems rather too much of a surprise, even for code which is designed to redesign the output layout rather radically.

Comment: @cfr `l3galley`  doesn't re-write the OR,  but  do know what you mean :)

Comment: @cfr I now added an issue to the tracker.